# change size array on run time in c

Tags: c

This my code in C , I am trying to change the array size dynamically but it get me to null pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
char *message = {"xxzz"};

message=realloc(message,5 * sizeof(*message));


if ( message == NULL)printf("Memory exhausted\n");

printf("%s",message);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MustafaGenç: You obviously read the question text. Great job!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only pass an pointer to `realloc` which was allocated memory using `malloc` or `calloc` or other memory allocating functions.
Failing to do so results in Undefined Behavior, that is what you have in your code.

Comment: so, what is the solution to my case?

Comment: @user1261494: Allocate memory to `message` using `malloc`/`calloc`

Comment: @user1261494 -- Since you know that the array is 5 bytes long, why not just allocate it longer?

Comment: sizeof(*message) will give you 1; you should use sizeof(message)

Comment: It is just a sample example. so, is there is solution without using realloc ?

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
char *message = malloc(5);
```